# Fulltext search not displaying exact search results

Tags: php, mysql, regex, search

i have job portal website. I am suing fulltext search for searching user keywords.
my table contains job_id, job_content  columns
When users searches 4 keywords at a time then i need to display mininum 3 words matching results. But i am also getting two words matching results also. I want only the job_content contains atleast 3 search words in that 4 words.

This is the code what i wrote

```
$jtitle=explode(" ",$_REQUEST['job_title']);

$mch=" (MATCH(t.job_title) AGAINST('+$jtitle[0] +$jtitle[1] +$jtitle[2] +$jtitle[3]' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
 or MATCH(t.job_title) AGAINST('+$jtitle[0] +$jtitle[1] +$jtitle[2]' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
or MATCH(t.job_title) AGAINST('+$jtitle[1] +$jtitle[2] +$jtitle[3]' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
or MATCH(t.job_title) AGAINST('+$jtitle[0] +$jtitle[1] +$jtitle[3]' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
 or MATCH(t.job_title) AGAINST('+$jtitle[0] +$jtitle[2] +$jtitle[3]' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
or MATCH(t.job_content) AGAINST('+$jtitle[0] +$jtitle[1] +$jtitle[2] +$jtitle[3]' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
or MATCH(t.job_content) AGAINST('+$jtitle[0] +$jtitle[1] +$jtitle[1]' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
or MATCH(t.job_content) AGAINST('+$jtitle[1] +$jtitle[2] +$jtitle[3]' IN BOOLEAN MODE)        
or MATCH(t.job_content) AGAINST('+$jtitle[0] +$jtitle[1] +$jtitle[3]' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
 or MATCH(t.job_content) AGAINST('+$jtitle[0] +$jtitle[2] +$jtitle[3]' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
          or MATCH(t.job_content) AGAINST('+$jtitle[0] +$jtitle[1] +$jtitle[3]' IN BOOLEAN MODE) )";
$qry=mysql_query(" select * from jobs where 1=1 and $mch ")
```

i wrote query like this for displaying atleast 3 keywords matching in jb_content or job_title results when user searches 4 words.
Problem is i am getting 2 words matching also.

Please help me how to solve this one for getting exact words results

Comment: You will need to hire thousands of developers for 6-words queries:)

Comment: tell me any query is in simple manner

Comment: It's a little joke. But your query scares me. There must be rules to get better performances and simplicity.

Comment: It could be better to let mysql decides which job offer is the most relevant: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html